# Finding differences between Pi with varying number of decimals

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I have the following code

```
In[32]:= N[Pi, 2]

Out[32]= 3.1

In[33]:= N[Pi, 1]

Out[33]= 3.

In[34]:= N[Pi, 2] - N[Pi, 1]

Out[34]= 0.*10^-1
```

Why can't Mathematica find the difference between the two numbers?

Comment: I'd bet there's a red box around the result... learn about *Precision* and *Accuracy* in the documentation, *Mathematica* is giving you what you've asked for.

Comment: @rasher this is not immediately clear to new users (or old ones w/o special need for `Precision` and the like), so might deserve some explanation.

Comment: @YvesKlett: Or, I suppose those who blithely use software without bothering to even skim the documentation. It is, after all, covered in gruesome detail within the first sections...

Comment: @rasher not so sure about the documentation here - there is no link to `Precision` or `Accuracy` in the `N` documentation, and the effect in combination with `Plus` can be puzzling. Not all *Mathematica* users are computer scientists (count me in).

Comment: @YvesKlett: Don't know what version you're on, but doc. center for 9.x has (among others) *six* links to tutorials and guides relating to accuracy and precision under 'N', and the second section of the virtual book covers it deeply. No big deal, but kind of a "why does the front of my car get all wrinkled-up when I bang it into a brick wall" kind of thing.

Comment: @rasher agreed, but you need to dig into the 4th link of those to meet `Precision`. I am not complaining about there being insufficient info, but I think this question nicely demonstrates some aspects that are not so easily found/interpreted, esp. for new users.

Comment: It's hardly limited to Mathematica users. SO is loaded with questions from n--bs in every language who haven't figured out the difference between stored values and displayed values (let alone rounded values!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`N` does not round numbers or truncate them.

The internal forms of

```
N[Pi, 1] // FullForm
N[Pi, 2] // FullForm
```

are respectively

```
(*
  3.1415926535897932384626433832795028842`1.
  3.1415926535897932384626433832795028842`2.
*)
```

Note that the numerical values are identical although the precisions differ.  Their difference is zero and all significant digits are lost.  The Front End *typesets* numerical results in `StandardForm` by showing only the significant digits determined by their precision.

This may be closer to what you're after:

```
Table[
 N[Floor[Pi, 10^n] - Floor[Pi, 10^(n + 1)]],
 {n, 0, -5, -1}]
(*
  {3.,
   0.1,
   0.04,
   0.001,
   0.0005,
   0.00009}
*)
```

---

**Update to incorporate some of the related points made in the comments:**

According to the tutorial [NumericalPrecision](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html#16838),
a nonzero approximate number `x` with precision `p` is defined to have uncertainty `Abs[x] 10^-p`.  Likewise, the precision of a nonzero approximate number `x` with uncertainty `d` is given by `-Log10[d/Abs[x]]`.

If approximate numbers are added or subtracted, the uncertainties are added.  There are similar such rules for other arithmetic operations and the evaluation of functions.  Consequently given two numbers $x_1,x_2$ with uncertainties $d_1,d_2$, the precision of $x_1\pm x_2$ is given by
$$ p = -\log_{10}\left({d_1+d_2 \over |\,x_1\pm x_2|} \right)\,.$$

In the OP's case the precision would be negative (negative infinity at that).  In cases where the precision is negative, *Mathematica* returns zero with corresponding computed accuracy.

Here is an illustration from the old comments.  The function `precDiff[{x1, p1}, {x2, p2}]` computes the precision of the difference of numbers `x1`, `x2` with precisions `p1`, `p2`.

```
precDiff[{x1_, p1_}, {x2_, p2_}] :=
   -Log10[(10^-p1 Abs[x1] + 10^-p2 Abs[x2])/Abs[x1 - x2]]
```

This shows that the computed precision of `N[34/10, 2] - N[Pi, 1]` is negative.

```
N @ precDiff[{34/10, 2}, {Pi, 1}]
N[34/10, 2] - N[Pi, 1] // FullForm
(*
  -0.129473
   0``0.4582220427094728
*)
```

This shows that the computed precision of `N[35/10, 2] - N[Pi, 1]` agrees with *Mathematica*'s .

```
N @ precDiff[{35/10, 2}, {Pi, 1}]
N[35/10, 2] - N[Pi, 1] // FullForm
(*
  0.0113533
  0.35840734641020676153735661672049580005`0.011353331924907081
*)
```

Comment: Speak of this, I feel quite confused about how _Mathematica_ decide the precision of the result produced by the calculation of numbers with arbitrary precision. (For this case, `Precision[N[Pi, 2] - N[Pi, 1]]` outputs `0.`, while one may guess the result should be `1.` by intuition. ) The document seems not to explain this… have I missed something?

Comment: +1 for illumination of what you see vs what's there. I thought of putting `AccountingForm@(N@First@RealDigits[N[Pi, 20]]*10^Range[0, -19, -1])` in my OP, but not sure what results questioner is after.

Comment: @xzczd The numerical difference is zero: they're both the same `3.14..` - the 1 and 2 at the end just indicate the precision.  `N` approximates `Pi` to a number of extra digits -- the docs say it will do this.  However, it returns a result with the requested precision.

Comment: @rasher Thanks and +1 to you, too, for a nice explanation of the general situation.

Comment: Then how to explain the result of `a = N[34/10, 2] - N[Pi, 1]; SetPrecision[a, 3]`?

Comment: @xzczd Your `a` is effectively zero and there's no version of zero with positive, finite precision so `SetPrecision` returns the closest thing it could. Arguably, though, `0.0` would have been more natural.

Comment: @MarkMcClure But according to Michael E2's explanation, a non-zero value which can be exposed by `FullForm` should be hidden in `a`, since `34/10` and `Pi` have numerical difference :)

Comment: Yeah, that's just where I feel confused, the rule for the decision of the precision isn't so clear here. Maybe I should start a new question?

Comment: Nice update. It's a pity that I can't upvote twice for one post :)

Answer (score 9):

*Mathematica* does not, by default, act like most calculators that will spew out digits in a result whether or not they are "valid" or "real" digits.

In most modes of usage, *Mathematica* keeps track of the precision of inputs, intermediate calculations, etc. and attempts to return results where the digits are correct, accurate, and "justified", that is, given a low-precision input applied to a high-precision input calculation, *Mathematica* will return results to the degree of precision warranted - you may better know this as *significant digits*. In fact, if you mouse-over the red box around the results you undoubtedly see, *Mathematica* will *tell* you what's going on "No significant digits are available to display."

You can see the effect of *Mathematica*'s accuracy tracking by "forcing" the issue, e.g.:

```
8``1*8``1
```

returns

```
6.*10^1
```

instead of the `64` you might expect, because in the above example we've in essence told *Mathematica* the limits of the significance of our input.

Along with the manual control of such things, as alluded to earlier, *Mathematica* tracks how the values are used in calculations, and adjusts what is considered "significant" along the way to the end results, so they are displayed with no "false precision". You can observe this easily:

```
ListPlot[Accuracy /@ NestList[4 # (1 - #) &, 1/8`20, 20], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Note that as the repeated calculation progresses, using prior results to produce new ones, *Mathematica* adjusts the significance accordingly.

There is no better place to get the details than *Mathematica*'s own documentation, e.g.:

[Numbers (overview)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumbersOverview.html)

[Precision and accuracy control](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/PrecisionAndAccuracyControl.html)

[Exact and approximate results](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html)

[Numerical evaluation and precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NumericalEvaluationAndPrecision.html)

[How to control the precision and accuracy of numerical results](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html)

And a couple (of many) excellent posts at this very site :

[Very different results...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32782/very-different-results-from-evaluating-same-expression-with-different-precisions/32869#32869)

[When can I assume...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27505/when-i-can-assume-that-all-decimal-digits-returned-by-mathematica-are-provably-c?lq=1)