# How can I obtain more significant digits?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I type

```
f1[x_] := 12 x^5 - 975 x^4 + 28000 x^3 - 345000 x^2 + 1800000 x
N[f1[15.5], 15]
```

and obtain
3.74112*10^6

BUT It´s not true!!! the result is larger than this solution, I think... BACAUSE...

```
 RealDigits[f1[15.5]]
```

gives me, the result
{{3, 7, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 6, 8, 7, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 7}

So,... I can´t understand that I tell Mathematica that I want to view 15 significative digits, and Mathematica DON´T show me 15 sgnificative digits!!!, only 6!!

How I can obtain more digits????  with N[...] or with //N ???

---

I can´t understand any differneces in precision with Mathematica

```
m1 = {15, 4, 8, 23, 10, 9, 5, 18, 30, 21}
m2 = {15`9, 4`9, 8`9, 23`9, 10`9, 9`9, 5`9, 18`9, 30`9, 21`9}
f1[x_] := 12 x^5 - 975 x^4 + 28000 x^3 - 345000 x^2 + 1800000 x
x0 = f1[m1]
x1 = N[f1[m1], 9]
x2 = N[f1[m2], 9]
```

In the last element of x_ you can see diferrences, and... I  don´t know what is the best way to obtain an an result with a concrete number os significative digits.

In x2, I tell Mathematica that I want 9 significative digits but the result is different from the last element of x1 and x0

and

I don´t know what result is the correct!

What´s the best way to obtain the good result with a given precision??, in this concrete situation?

If you replace in the las line of code in x2  9 for 12 or 15, you obtain the same result!!  I can´t understand the behaivour!!

Comment: Simple way: `N[f1[15 + 1/2], 15]`. See e.g., here (and references cited) for why: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43714/finding-differences-between-pi-with-varying-number-of-decimals/43716#43716

Comment: @rasher I´m gratefull to you for the link. But... I think that is a simple question that is not simply explained in the documentation. Almost, for me. I have read about that issue and... the only solution I encoutered is use a higeher number in precsion but still can´t understand the behaivour of Mathematica in this sense. I supose that the precision is use in all the process of calculations so... I reach after trying examples that I still must read a message about a red box rounded a result with text "No significantiv.." and still trying to understand. But... Thank you reasher for the link

Comment: Related: [(10624)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10624/121), [(55292)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55292/121),
[(72454)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72454/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies with your 15.5 which has a small precision. `Mathematica` won't try to add digits beyond machine precision for this. `Mathematica` by default only displays 6 digits of precision unless otherwise specified. To view all the digits, wrap the output in `InputForm`.

To specify your precision, try this:

```
N[f1[15.5`15],15]
```

Or even this:

```
N[f1[Rationalize[15.5]],15]
```

Compare the differences in these three inputs:

```
Precision[15.5]

Precision[15.5`15]

Precision[Rationalize[15.5](*or 31/2*)]
```

Comment: Ok, for 15 works well, but... N[f1[15.5`4], 4] dont give me 4 significantive digits! ONLY 2!  and N[f1[15.5`5], 5] ONLY 3 digits!

Comment: $f1[Rationalize[123.456789]]=\frac{41327339867286004045456962819021417698847}{250000000000000000000000000000}$