# Why does NumberForm disturb the output of Rationalize?

Tags: conditional, output-formatting

I am currently using `Rationalize` after `NumberForm` in order to check if the some values of my function are in the `Rationals`. Unfortunately, using `NumberForm` completely breaks Mathematica's output.

I have the following minimal reproducible example:

```
For[i = 1, i < 20, i += 1, (
  x = Rationalize@NumberForm[i/(i + 1), 32];
  If[Element[x, Rationals], Print[x]]
  )]
```

The above code checks whether $\frac{i}{i+1}$ is rational, for integer $1\leq i<20$. Unexpectedly, it outputs *nothing*.

Even more unexpectedly, the following code, which is supposed to print $x$ no matter what, also outputs *nothing*:

```
For[i = 1, i < 20, i += 1, (
  x = Rationalize@NumberForm[i/(i + 1), 32];
  If[Element[x, Rationals], Print[x], Print[x]]
  )]
```

Note the difference in the `If` clause.

> So why does Mathematica fail to detect the rational values, even after `Rationalize`?

I am using Mathematica 11.1.

---

Note that I added the **bugs** tag. Feel free to remove it if adequate.

Comment: Take a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92226/5478, does it answer your question?

Comment: SeedRandom[12345];
For[i=1,i<20,i+=1,
j=If[RandomReal[]<0.5,i,RandomReal[{1.0,20.0}]];
x0=j/(j+1.0);
x1=Rationalize@x0;
Print[If[Denominator[x1]<=40,x1,x0]//InputForm]
]