# N, machine precision and expression evaluation

Tags: machine-precision

I should state that I am a *Mathematica* beginner but I checked the questions about machine vs arbitrary precision (such as: [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55292/a-problem-about-function-n) ) and I continue to have the following issue while trying to evaluate an expression:

After various calculations which include square roots and integrals, I arrive at a function `foo[x_]` which I want it to return a number.
On the contrary, it returns a numerical expression as shown below, together with the return values of different tests I made.
[image]

My end goal is to use `foo` to calculate other expressions, as well as to `Plot` this it, which I cannot do at the moment.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably some problem with the definition of `foo`, which you do not provide...

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour]**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: You should definitely share the code for `foo` in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) so people can *Copy&Paste* it and test by themselves and try to reproduce your problem. Help us to help you, as it is, we can hardly do anything for you.

Comment: My guess would be that you have an invisible character somewhere in your code. It might provide some insight if you'd apply `FullForm` to some of your inputs and results.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your quick replies.
By checking your comments, I went back to the initial functions that formed the problematic final expression and was indeed a formatting error.
The problematic function in full form is the following:
[image: problematic]

I assume that the \.08 character is what is causing the problem as when I rewritten the Cos[y] factor the problem was gone for this function (as well as for the final complete expression) as shown below.
[image]

So finally it wasn't a machine precision error but a formatting error.
Once again thanks for your replies.