# Number definition and approximation

Tags: machine-precision, arbitrary-precision, output-formatting

I run these lines:

```
a = 0.833
SetPrecision[a, 20]
```

and this is the output:

```
0.833

0.83299999999999996270
```

I expected to receive

```
0.83300000000000000000
```

Do you have any suggestion? 
Thank you!

Comment: 0.833'20 gives what you expect, but `SetPrecision[a,20]` is equivalent to `N[FromDigits[RealDigits[a,2],2],20] = 0.83299999999999996270`. MMA works with binary numbers.

Comment: It works with 0.833'20, but not with a'20

Comment: The back tick is used in specifying numeric input. Using it on variables thus  ``a`20`` is not syntactically valid. The problem is that `a = 0.833` evaluates `0.833` in machine precision binary and obtains the binary floating point number nearest to `0.833`, but that number is only approximately equal to `0.833`.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55292/a-problem-about-function-n

Comment: You don't need `a'20`.  Just use `a=0.833'20` and `a` will have 20 digits of precision from then on or until it is reassigned.  That is supposed to be a back tick, but I can't write it that way because of the way comments treat back ticks.

Comment: @BillWatts Enclose single backticks within double backticks to get the backtick show.

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks.

Comment: N[Rationalize[0.033], 20]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `SetPrecision[833/1000 , 20]` or `SetPrecision[.833 // Rationalize, 20]`.