# Precision[] and Accuracy[] give non-integer result

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

```
a = N[Pi, {20, 19}];
Precision[a] (*19.497149872694134`*)
Accuracy[a](*19.`*)

Accuracy[a]*Log2[10] (*63.116633802859894`*)
```

#### My question

The `Precision[a]` value is a non-integer, which I don't know what it means. And the `Accuracy[a]*Log2[10]` isn't an integer either. 
How in the essence the Precision and Accuracy value is measured if not in the number of bit?

---

#### What I already know:

The number precision recision is measured in number of bit rather than number of decimals 
which I deduce by Official Doc about [Number Precision](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html#21155):

> Note that to achieve full consistency in the treatment of numbers,
>   precision and accuracy often have values that do not correspond to
>   integer numbers of digits.

Therefore the following code runs like :

```
$MachinePrecision 
(*15.954589770191003`*)
$MachinePrecision == 53/Log2[10] 
(*True*)
```

---

## Updated 2020-05-11 00:38:50

In an arbitrary-precision number `x` with precision `p`, the definition of `p` is:  $p=-\log _{10}\left(\frac{\text{dx}}{x}\right)$, in which `dx` is the amount of uncertainty. We are using `x` to approximate an unknown real number y lying in the open interval `(x-dx x+dx)`.

For example:

```
Clear["*"]
prec = 300;
x = N[Pi, prec];
xAsPreciseValue = 
 SetPrecision[x, 
  prec + 1];(*Here has to be prec+1,to avoid the roundoff made by \
SetPrecision*)
dx = xAsPreciseValue*10^-prec;
N[-Log[10, dx/xAsPreciseValue]](*output 990 as expected*)
Block[
 {Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0},
 TrueQ[
  xAsPreciseValue - dx < Pi < xAsPreciseValue + dx
  ]

 ](*output  all True as expected*)
```

About the necessity of **Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0** in the inequality, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626748/5361482)

Comment: It's explained pretty clear in the documentation for those function, isn't it? (E.g., "With absolute uncertainty dx, Precision[x] is -Log[10,dx/x].")

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh please give me a link, I cannot find anything even with your keyword:"With absolute uncertainty "

Comment: @MichaelE2 Found it using your keyword "With absolute uncertainty" in Google. But I still don't know what does it mean by `dx`. Really appreciate if you could elaborate on it"

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156390/4999. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124830/4999 -- HTH! :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Everything is here, it's just damn hard to filter it out…

Comment: @MichaelE2 I spent the whole day reading through many of your answers on numeric precision. It's really profound and rigorous. However I still have many questions. Please see my edited question above.

Comment: Try ``Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0},
 xAsPreciseValue - dx < Pi < xAsPreciseValue + dx
 ]`` (ref. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86819/4999)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have time to write a complete response to your question. As you have noticed, the numeric environments in *Mathematica* are complicated. There is one exact one and two approximate ones, machine precision and arbitrary-precision (and arguably another when you set `$MinPrecision` and `$MaxPrecision`). Further, in the approximate ones, comparisons `<`. `==`, etc. are made "with tolerance," which can cause further confusion. E.g., the transitive properties of `<`, `==` do not always hold. The answer to your question would be long and repeat much of what has already been written.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ``Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0`` worked, I'm searching things about `EqualTolerance`, thanks a lot!