# Why is my data 10 times slower than random data when doing matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, numerics

I have some data generated from some program, and it appears that matrix multiplication on these data are about 10 times slower than on some random data:

```
Get["tb.dat"];

xls = Range[-500, 500, 1000/(1000 - 1)] // N;

Re[Conjugate[#].(xls*#)] & /@ tb; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.067147, Null} *)

tb2 = RandomComplex[{0., 1. + I}, Dimensions[tb]];

Re[Conjugate[#].(xls*#)] & /@ tb2; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.004564, Null} *)
```

So what are the reasons for the performance problem with my data?

The data files are [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24667921/tb.dat) (6MB).

---

**Update**

Here is the same problem with the packed array. Since [Save unpacks data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5268/1364), so I have to use DumpSave to demonstrate the problem:

```
DumpGet["tb3PK.dump"];

Developer`PackedArrayQ@tb3PK
(* True *)

xls = Range[-500, 500, 1000/(1000 - 1)] // N;

Re[Conjugate[#].(xls*#)] & /@ tb3PK; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.065747, Null} *)

tb2 = RandomComplex[{0., 1. + I}, Dimensions[tb3PK]];

Re[Conjugate[#].(xls*#)] & /@ tb2; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.003482, Null} *)
```

The file tb3PK.dump is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24667921/Data%20for%20Mathematica%20StackExchange%20Questions/data%20slower%20than%20random%20data/tb3PK.dump) . I'm using OS X 10 and Mathematica version 10.0.1

Comment: It is because your data is not packed, but data generated by `RandomComplex` is. Try this: ``{{Developer`PackedArrayQ@tb, ByteCount@tb},{Developer`PackedArrayQ@tb2, ByteCount@tb2}}``. However according to what I have learned about packed arrays, your data should be packable because `Equal @@ Map[Head, tb, {2}]` is true, i.e. all of your elements are of the same type. However, ``Developer`PackedArrayQ@Developer`ToPackedArray[tb]`` returns `False`. I am not writing this as an answer as I hope that an answer will address how to pack your data.

Comment: @Pickett No wonder `tb3=Developer``ToPackedArray[tb]` is as slow as the unpacked data. I didn't know that Developer`ToPackedArray could fail to pack an array without giving any error message.

Comment: Computing the following `Tally[ByteCount /@ Flatten[tb]]` shows that some of your numbers have different byte counts due to large exponents. I doubt the data can be packed.

Comment: Re update: It's because the calculation is resulting in numbers that are not machine-sized numbers.  In such a case, *Mathematica* automatically converts them to arbitrary precision numbers, which take longer to calculate.  Also the result is not packed. -- Compare with `tb2 = RandomComplex[{$MinMachineNumber, 1. + I $MinMachineNumber}, Dimensions[tb3PK]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 but why the problem still exists even when I set `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]`, it seems to me if the problem is caused by the auto convention to high precision, turn off it would resolve the problem ?

Comment: What makes you think that option prevents the automatic conversion?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I thought the option removes the process of catching underflow as its name suggested. Also I read from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeOptions.html) that RuntimeOptions->"Speed" is equivalent to turning off those underflow or overflow catch, which seem to suggest that those catches would take extra time.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure.  Setting it to False speeds it up, but only by a factor of 4.  Perhaps there's a cost to underflow even when it is not "caught."  Someone else is going to have to answer this.  Sorry.

Comment: @MichaelE2 No problem, your comments are already very helpful for me. Thanks:)

Comment: Where did you get that DumpGet from? It's not documented.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I guessed it :)

Comment: Get on its own should work. DumpGet has no doc page, though there exists an error [page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/DumpGet/bgbf.html).

Answer (score 13):

For readers who didn't read all the comments, the slowdown is due to a lack of [packing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) of `tb`, whereas `RandomReal` returns packed arrays when more than 250 elements are  generated. The reason why packing `tb` fails is because some elements have different precision than others, and (I think?) `ToPackedArray` requires arrays to be of homogeneous type.

To fix this, chop and multiply by `1. + 0. I`, then pack:

```
<< Developer`
tbP = ToPackedArray[(1. + 0. I) Chop@tb];
PackedArrayQ[tb2]
Re[Conjugate[#].(xls*#)] & /@ tb; // AbsoluteTiming
Re[Conjugate[#].(xls*#)] & /@ tbP; // AbsoluteTiming
```

producing

```
True
{0.031200, Null}
{0., Null}
```

Does anyone know a better way of taking an array composed of heterogeneous-precision real and complex numbers, and converting it into an array of homogeneous-precision complex numbers? The above trick works, but I feel like there ought to be a better way.

#### Update

To address the Update in your question, I'm stumped. Comparing the `DumpSave` output with the solution I used above:

```
DumpGet["tb3PK.dump"];
Re[Conjugate[#].(xls*#)] & /@ tbP; // AbsoluteTiming
Re[Conjugate[#].(xls*#)] & /@ tb3PK; // AbsoluteTiming
Tally[Precision /@ Flatten[tbP]]
Tally[Precision /@ Flatten[tb3PK]]
ByteCount[tbP]
ByteCount[tb3PK]
```

giving

```
{0., Null}
{0.040000, Null}
{{MachinePrecision, 100000}}
{{MachinePrecision, 100000}}
1600152
1600152
```

In other words, the `DumpSave` version is indeed slower as you observed, despite having the same bytecount and precision, and I'm not sure why. You may want to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Could use `N[array]`.

Comment: I think the numbers in the tb are all `MachinePrecision`, for example `And @@ ((Precision[#] == MachinePrecision &) /@ tb)` returns `True`. Also I'm interested in the log spectrum of the data, where small numbers are important to me, so I would prefer to not Chop if possible.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Using `N[tb]` and then packing fails to pack the array, because the result is still heterogeneous-precision.

Comment: @xslittlegrass: `Tally[Precision /@ Flatten[tb]]` shows that most, but not all elements are `MachinePrecision`.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Those few numbers have precisions like `15.954589770191005`, and if you compare with Machine precision, it return true `15.954589770191005` == MachinePrecision`.

Comment: @xslittlegrass: It's strange: one number with `MachinePrecision` occupies 56 bytes, and another with precision `15.9546` occupies 216 bytes. I'm not sure why this is the case. Hopefully someone else will answer with a better explanation. In the mean time, I noticed that the largest elements of your array have absolute value of about 0.6, so if a log-spectrum of your data is needed, then hopefully `Chop` will only affect the very-very-low-amplitude areas of your plot. Otherwise, you may have to use the slower, but more precise unpacked array `tb`.

Comment: @xslittlegrass: Also, you can control the delta-cutoff of `Chop`, for example, you can use `ToPackedArray[(1.0 + 0.0 I) Chop[tb, 10^-32]]`. I haven't tested it to see if it works properly, though.

Comment: If `N` is not creating floats, that typically means there are numbers outside the range of floats (and they will have precision numerically equal to `N[MachinePrecision]`, if they were computed at `machinePrecision`). I assume they are small rather than large in magnitude, and so your `Chop` suggestion seems like a viable way to proceed.

Comment: @xslittlegrass `15.954589770191005 == MachinePrecision` does return `True`, but when using as precision, they're different, the latter represents machine precision, while the former represents arbitrary precision, they lead to 2 different algorithm… well, it's a little hard for me to explain in my own words, but there're many related posts in this site, for example [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32869/1871).

Answer (score 2):

I propose a silly workaround, instead of a workable explanation:

```
Get["tb.dat"];

xls = Range[-500, 500, 1000/(1000 - 1)] // N;
test[tb_] := (Re[Conjugate[#].(xls*#)] & /@ tb;) // AbsoluteTiming;
test[RandomComplex[{0., 1. + I}, Dimensions[tb]]]
(* {0.002002, Null} *)
test[tb]
(* {0.040038, Null} *)
test[tb + ConstantArray[0. + 0. I, Dimensions@tb]]
(* {0.003003, Null} *)
test[tb (1.0 + 0. I)]
(* {0.002002, Null} *)
```

This tricks Mathematica into doing the right thing. I find it often (too often) helps a lot to multiply with `1.`, or just add `0.`. From my tests it doesn't seem to matter if you multiply by `(1.0 + 0. I)` or add a constant array, you get the same performance boost. It also doesn't seem to matter if the array is packed or not.