# How can we ensure the result of Mathematica is exactly correct?

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

This is an example, I plot a function and find it has a defect when x approximates 400.

```
Plot[Cos[.3 x] Exp[-0.01 x], {x, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example, we calculate the orbit of planet motion. As we know, the orbit of planet is ellipse when the total energy is negative. However, if we calculate it in a long time, the result will deviate from ellipse markedly - while *Mathematica* has no any warning or message here!

The code and result showed below:

```
M = 4; a = 700; (*a is the total time of this simulation*)
s = 
    NDSolve[{x''[t] == -((GM (x[t] + 1))/((x[t] + 1)^2 + y[t]^2)^1.5), 
             y''[t] == -((GM y[t])/((x[t] + 1)^2 + y[t]^2)^1.5), y[0] == 2, 
             x[0] == .3, x'[0] == .2, y'[0] == -.1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, a}, 
             MaxSteps -> 10^8];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, a}]
```

[image]

What I wonder is how to make sure *Mathematica*'s result is exactly correct? When we find something special with *Mathematica*, how can we know it is a new thing, or just a wrong result of *Mathematica*?

Comment: Related, I believe: [When I can assume that all decimal digits returned by Mathematica are provably correct?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27505)

Comment: A good start is understanding proper use of *Mathematica*, how built-ins (and their options) work, etc. (e.g. `PlotPoints`, `MaxRecursion` and `Method` in your plot *visualization* example). The documentation is pretty good pointing out gotchas and their effects and ways to avoid them.

Comment: For me, a good approach would be also to use another, redundant, tool- for those extremely important results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply increase `PlotPoints`:

```
Plot[Cos[.3 x] Exp[-0.01 x], {x, 0, 1000}, 
 PlotRange -> {{300, 500}, {-0.05, 0.05}}, ImageSize -> 600, PlotPoints -> 2000]
```

[image]

Increasing `PlotPoints` would also draw a smooth ellipse in your orbit example

Comment: I am sorry, but this does not attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Sektor - I am sorry too, but my tip _attempts_ to answer the question. Using `Plot` and `ParametricPlot` YOU have to decide how many `PlotPoints` you want or need. When you use `Table` and then `ListLinePlot` with the above example you get the same smooth image, i.e. the numerics are correct.

Comment: So, you are telling me that this answers the question "How to make sure *Mathematica*'s result is exactly correct?" ?!

Comment: I am not saying it is not related, but to consider it an answer ...

Comment: @Sektor - I now answer the question:  "How to make sure Mathematica's result is exactly correct?" Answer: With pencil and paper like in the good all days :)

Comment: Good for you :) We should all upvote your answer then :)

Comment: Thank you all. In fact, I knew PlotPoints can improve it, but I don't know how much PlotPoints is enough,

Comment: @S.Lai - just start with a large number, f.e, I used 2000 for the ellipse. A smooth plot came immediately with `a = 1000` and `GM = 0.9`.

Comment: I think this answers the issue that caused the question (+1). The title of the question is too broad to allow a better answer.

Comment: I would interpret the answer this way: "As you see, in this particular case, you can do something to make Mathematica be more accurate. Try similar in any other situation." This makes this answer fine, and really a nice and useful answer to the question.

Comment: @VividD I think your opinion is appropriate.