# How to check the decimal accuracy of result?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I am trying to check if the result is enough accurate to use. I need an accuracy of 10^-6 from some numerical method. Something like root finding algorithm. But how do I check that in mathematica? I looked over Accuracy[] and Precision[] but they are quite confusing in that they yield machineprecision. Can anyone suggest something? Thank you for help :)

Comment: Excellent answers here: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27505/when-i-can-assume-that-all-decimal-digits-returned-by-mathematica-are-provably-c)

Comment: You should know also about a related topic: [Meaning of backtick in floating-point literal](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/meaning-of-backtick-in-floating-point-literal)

Comment: Welcome to M.SE.  Posting a minimal example code will help us help you better.  At the moment, all that community members can do is point you to other resources that may/may not be less confusing that what you've read in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
(root = x /. FindRoot[x*Tan[x] - Cos[x] == 0, {x, 3}]) // InputForm
```

> 2.8170396080933187

```
root // Precision
```

> MachinePrecision

Your machine precision is seen with $MachinePrecision

```
$MachinePrecision
```

> 15.9546

```
root2 = x /. FindRoot[x*Tan[x] - Cos[x] == 0, {x, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

> 2.8170396080933199925

```
root2 // Precision
```

> 20.