# Comparing exact expressions for equality -- is it really OK if I get wrong answer?

Tags: bugs, evaluation, numerics, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

I found an unexpected behavior (that I think of as a bug) in evaluation of the equality operator applied to mathematical functions with exact arguments (i.e. not containing any approximate floating-point numbers):

```
AppellF1[1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 3/2, 1/2 + I √3 / 2, 1/2 - I √3 / 2] == EllipticK[3/4] / 2
(* False *)
```

This result is wrong. In fact, these two expressions are equal, so the ideal correct result would be `True`. I understand that *Mathematica* may not be able to immediately prove this equality, so it could return it unevaluated.

I guess that the wrong answer `False` is a result of round-off errors occurred when *Mathematica* tried to evaluate both operands numerically. But I believe that numerical approximations should only be used to decide equality if precision is enough to establish provably non-zero difference.

Here are some excerpts from *Mathematica* help confirming this point:

> When given precise numbers, the Wolfram Language does not convert them to an approximate representation, but gives a precise result.
>
> ---
>
> When `Equal` cannot decide whether two numeric expressions are equal it returns unchanged.

I reported this issue to *support@wolfram.com* (CASE:3353933), but received a response saying this is not a bug. *Update: we followed up on this issue and agreed that it's indeed a bug.*

So I would like to know your opinion, whether this behavior is indeed by design?

Comment: [May be a related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27505/7288)

Comment: Just to check your conjecture that `Equal` is using `N[]` internally, try doing `InputForm[N[(* number *)]]` on each constant. You might also want to try varying the setting of the system variable ``Internal`$EqualTolerance``.

Comment: As far as I can tell `Equal` does what it's supposed to, the incorrect result is due to the `AppelF1` evaluation at high precision not being sufficiently accurate. It should definitely be looked at and I'll let the developers know.

Comment: To verify @ilian's note, maybe somebody can do a `Table[]` of the Appell function value evaluated at different levels of precision… the elliptic integral I would expect to be very accurately evaluated, as that is computed using AGM.

Comment: @ Vladimir Reshetnikov : at least numerically things are alright  (N[AppellF1[1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 3/2, 1/2 + I \[Sqrt]3/2, 1/2 - I \[Sqrt]3/2]] // Chop) == N[EllipticK[3/4]/2] (* True *)

Comment: Fixed in version 10.2.

Comment: @ilian Great, thanks! May I ask, what was the root cause?

Comment: As in the comment above (`AppellF1` evaluation at high precision not being sufficiently accurate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first suspected that the small imaginary component in the numeric approximation was the source of the problem but adding [`Re`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html) did not change the `False` result.  Next I checked to see if the first fifty digits matched and they do:

```
x1 = AppellF1[1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 3/2, 1/2 + I √3/2, 1/2 - I √3/2];

x2 = EllipticK[3/4]/2;

Equal @@ RealDigits[{Re@x1, x2}, 10, 50]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

However in the next fifty digits a mismatch is reported:

```
Equal @@ RealDigits[{Re@x1, x2}, 10, 50, -50]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
RealDigits[{Re@x1, x2}, 10, 10, -88]
```

> ```
> {{{5, 8, 2, 9, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 8}, -87},
>  {{9, 3, 7, 8, 9, 0, 7, 2, 2, 9}, -87}}
> ```

I then tried increasing [`$MinPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MinPrecision.html) with the same result:

```
Block[{$MinPrecision = 500},
  RealDigits[{Re@x1, x2}, 10, 10, -88]
]
```

However if I apply [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) first the digits are reported to match:

```
RealDigits[{Re@x1, x2} ~N~ 200, 10, 10, -88]

{{{9, 3, 7, 8, 9, 0, 7, 2, 2, 9}, -87},
 {{9, 3, 7, 8, 9, 0, 7, 2, 2, 9}, -87}}
```

I do not feel qualified to interpret the meaning of this but I would have expected this output to match the former one.  I *thought* that `RealDigits` was the more robust tool and that all the digits it reported for an exact number would be correct.  Perhaps this is not the case.  Or perhaps this reveals a bug somewhere?

Comment: What happens if you do ``Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = (* tiny number *)}, x1 == x2]``? and vary that system variable accordingly? (Maybe `$MachineEpsilon` is a good first setting to try?)

Comment: @J. M. Strangely after performing the evaluations for the answer above `x1 == x2` then returned unevaluated!  After restarting the kernel it again gave `False`!  I'll try to explore this more later.

Comment: `N` caches its results, so performing the 200-digit computation first makes the two `RealDigits` agree a bit further.

Comment: `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100},
 (N[x1 - x2, 20] // Chop[#, 10^-75] &) == 0]` returns `True`

Comment: @ilian I am confused by that; why isn't `RealDigits` giving correct(?) results?  Edit: I just saw your other comment above; so `N` forces a finer resolution of the value which is then cached?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, the caching comment was meant to expand on the last part of your answer. Also, for an exact number, `RealDigits` internally computes a numerical approximation (with sufficiently many extra digits beyond the requested) using the same code as `N` so it is susceptible to this kind of problem.