# Numeric calculation with many digits

Tags: numerics, numerical-value

I try to calculate something like 1.569732312*Pi and by default mathematica returns something like 4.93146 (only 5 digits after floating point), but I believe there is much more digits, especially because Pi has infinite number of digits.

if I do like this

```
N[1.569732312*Pi, 50]
```

It still return the same 5 digits 4.93146

As I understand from documentation, I have to use Rationalize[]. If I do like this

```
N[Rationalize[1.569732312]*Pi, 50]
```

result is the same 4.93146

and only if I remove 3 digits like this

```
N[Rationalize[1.569732]*Pi, 50]
```

it gives me all digits like this

```
4.9314585193048133197984421233221006214165911156199
```

What I am doing wrong and how to calculate 1.569732312*Pi with 50 digits precision?

Comment: 1.569732312`50*Pi - note the backtick. See also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27505/when-i-can-assume-that-all-decimal-digits-returned-by-mathematica-are-provably-c).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, if I put something like 1.569732312`50*Pi, it works fine.

Comment: 1.569732312 is a machine double. What 50 digit result would you expect to get from that product? (If you want a 50 digit number that has 1.569732312 followed by decimal zeroes, the tactic of using 1.569732312`50 as proposed by @corey979 is appropriate).

Comment: I want to know the result of my equation. Like Pi=3.1415926...., If I multiple it by 2, it will be 6,2831852, but I want to know all 50 digits of this equation 2*Pi, because Pi has infinite digits. and later I want to change 2 to some different number.

Comment: you should review the details section in the docs for `Rationalize` to learn whats happening there.

Comment: `Rationalize[1.569732312]` evaluates to `1.569732312` since from the documentation for [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)  "Rationalize[x] yields x unchanged if there is no rational number close enough to x to satisfy the condition |p/q-x| < c/q^2, with c chosen to be 10^-4."  Use `Rationalize[x, 0]` to `Rationalize` any number.

Comment: @BobHanlon Good point, thanks. I did not know.

Answer (score 1):

It is about backtick. This example works fine

```
1.569732312`50*Pi
```

Comment: Similarly, 2.0`50*Pi gives 2*Pi to 50 dgits