# Compare their asymptotic behaviour using the order notation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

For each pair of the following functions, compare their asymptotic behaviour using the order notation.
 f(n) = e^n and g(n)= 3n^2

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Is this even about the software Wolfram Mathematica or is it a math question?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica 12.0 has got tools to this end:

```
AsymptoticLess[Exp[n], 3 n^2, n -> Infinity]
*False*
AsymptoticGreater[Exp[n], 3 n^2, n -> Infinity]
*True*
AsymptoticEqual[Exp[n], 3 n^2, n -> Infinity]
*False*
```

See the documentation for more info.