# OutputResponse numerical error?

Tags: control-systems

[image]

It shoud approach to 1 and remains at 1, but when time over 20s it deteriorates.

Mathematica 12.1

```
Plot[OutputResponse[    Rationalize[
    TransferFunctionModel[
     Unevaluated[{{(0.045 (0.005 + s) (1 + 10. s))/(
       s^3 (1 + (0.09 (0.005 + s) (1 + 10. s))/(s^3 (2 + s))))}}], s, 
     SamplingPeriod ->None, SystemsModelLabels -> None]], UnitStep[t],
    t] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 40}]
```

Comment: Please show us the code text rather than the screenshot of it.

Comment: And, please don't add bugs tage before WRI or the community has confirmed it as a bug.

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27505/1871

Comment: ok . I am glad to be educated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is:

```
f = (0.045*(0.005 + s)*(1 + 10. s))/(s^3 (1 + (0.09*(0.005 + s)*(1 + 10. s))/(s^3*(2 + s))));

g = OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[{{f}}, s], UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 40}]

Plot[g, {t, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Workaround:

```
sys = Rationalize[(0.045*(0.005 + s)*(1 + 
     10. s))/(s^3 (1 + (0.09*(0.005 + s)*(1 + 10. s))/(s^3*(2 + 
          s)))), 0] // Factor // ExpandAll

u = UnitStep[t];
func = InverseLaplaceTransform[sys*LaplaceTransform[u, t, s], s, t];

Plot[func, {t, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: "`OutputResponse` can't be calculated analytically is very complex. Only way is by numerics." No, in this case it can. (Takes about 50 seconds on my laptop. ) We then just need a higher `WorkingPrecision`. Of course pure numeric approach shown by you is better.